# Dynamically call a method from a dynamically called class

Tags: php

I'm trying to call a controller and method pulled from the URI `site.com/controller/method`

Here is my current working code:

```
    $__REQUEST__ = new URI_Request($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

    $this->prepareController($__REQUEST__);

    if($this->checkClass()) {
        $this->controller = new $this->controller();

        if($this->checkMethod($__REQUEST__)) {
            $method = $__REQUEST__->getMethod();
            $this->method = $method;
            $this->controller->$method();
        }
    }
```

However, I want this line

```
$this->controller->$method();
```

To work as similarly to this

```
$this->controller = new $this->controller();
//achieves something like $this->controller = new IndexController();
//if the URL was something like site.com/index/test (/index/ gets manipulated)
```

i.e. something like

```
$this->controller->$this->method
```

I can see why this wouldn't work, however - is there a way to chain this or get it to reference the $method variable from the object characteristics rather than a stray variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->controller->{$this->method}();
```

Comment: Could you give a little context as to how it works? I'm not sure where I'd read up on this

Comment: @Jackhardcastle Dntknw ))

curly brackets this is "markers". I think, it begin from this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php